# rspec3: how to mock a paginated array?

Tags: rspec, rspec3

I'm using rspec3 and I'm trying to get a handle on the new double method verification feature.  I'd like to create a double for a paginated array like this:

```
my_array = object_double([])
allow(my_array).to receive(:current_page).and_return(1)
```

However, this results in this error:

```
Double[...] does not implement: current_page
```

This is because rspec is creates a verifying double when given object_double.  I really don't want to try to create a fake array double that responds to things like `:[]`.  Setting `mocks.verify_partial_doubles = false` globally also does not help (and also seems like overkill for this problem), presumably because an object_double is intended to be verifying.

I know I can just paginate my array before making a double of it, but I don't feel like I should have to do this.  Is there something I'm missing?  Should I request that rspec provide the ability to disable verification on a per-method basis, or provide the ability to create a non-verifying object double, or should I be writing this test some other way?

In the interim, I can write something like this:

```
  products = Class.new(SimpleDelegator) do
    def current_page
      1
    end
    def per_page
      1
    end
    def total_entries
      1
    end
  end.new([])
```

... but it doesn't look like a simple rspec mock any more.

Comment: *I know I can just paginate my array before making a double of it, but I don't feel like I should have to do this.* It seems you want to have your cake (test double) and eat (paginate) it too. Why not test the paginated array?

Comment: I guess I don't want to introduce a dependency on a particular paginator.